# improving randomForest running time

Tags: random-forest

This has already been asked and answered, but one of the answers didn't explain why a certain technique worked.

So my question is "Why does calling randomForest(predictors, decision) instead of the normal (decision~ predictors) reducing running time?

Comment: For data sets with something like less than ~2.000.000 fields, e.g. 4000 samples and 500 variables, I don't think the time difference is very noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

from randomForest help file:

> For large data sets, especially those with large number of variables, calling randomForest via the formula interface is not advised: There may be too much overhead in handling the formula.

The algorithms for the package randomForest is implemented in C. The R formula interface is not compatible with C. Before running low level algorithms the data must be ordered in a numeric feature matrix(X) and a target vector(y).